# Powershell: Supress the output to console if it is pipelined

Tags: powershell, return, output, suppress

I am writing a search tool on Powershell and I ran into a problem that I cannot suppress the return of a function and it is always printed to console. 
To make it clear I made some smaller test functions.

```
Function test1
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $PrevRes = 0)
    write-host "alfa"
    return ($PrevRes+1)
}

Function test2
{
 param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $PrevRes = 0)
    write-host "beta"
    return ($PrevRes+1) 
}

Function test3
{
 param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $PrevRes = 0)
    write-host "omega"
    return ($PrevRes+1)
}

test1 gives:  
alfa
1

when test1 | test2:
alfa
beta
2

when test | test2 | test3:
alfa
beta
omega
3

when test | test3 | test2:
alfa
omega
beta
3
```

The problem is I do not know in what order these functions will be called and what I need is to make sure if there is no pipeline at the end, the return would not be printed to the screen, but I still need to access the value itself.

I want an output like this:

```
test1 gives:  
alfa


when test1 | test2:
alfa
beta


when test | test2 | test3:
alfa
beta
omega


when test | test3 | test2:
alfa
omega
beta
```

This is a tool for a customer so solution like:

```
$tst = test1 |test2
```

is not good because you know, a customer is a customer, he wouldn't know how to use it.

Is there a way to do it with powershell which I missed online?

Any solution would be useful if it does not involve any action from the customer

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question

> is there a way to determine in the function itself if the return value is pipelined or not?

Yes there is. Inspect the `$MyInvocation` automatic variable and compare the `PipelineLength` and `PipelinePosition` properties:

```
if($MyInvocation.PipelinePosition -lt $MyInvocation.PipelineLength){
    return $PrevRes + 1
}
```

Original answer follows below.

---

Very simple solution:

## Don't use [`Write-Host`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) in your scripts.

As the name indicates, it will *write* stuff directly to the *host* application

If you need to keep these statements for debugging purposes, use the [`Write-Debug`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug) or [`Write-Verbose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose) cmdlets instead:

```
function test1
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $PrevRes = 0)
    Write-Verbose "alfa"
    return ($PrevRes+1)
}

function test2
{
 param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $PrevRes = 0)
    Write-Verbose "beta"
    return ($PrevRes+1) 
}

function test3
{
 param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $PrevRes = 0)
    Write-Verbose "omega"
    return ($PrevRes+1)
}
```

---

If you need to increment the `$PrevRes` value between cmdlets you could use a variable from the calling scope (although this is somewhat of an anti-pattern, and I would strongly recommend against it):

```
function test1 {
  Write-Host 'alpha'
  $global:PrevRes++
}

function test2 {
  Write-Host 'beta'
  $global:PrevRes++
}

function test3 {
  Write-Host 'omega'
  $global:PrevRes++
}
```

Then use like:

```
PS> test1; test2; test3
alpha
beta
omega
PS> $PrevRes
3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but I am sorry maybe my question was not self explaining. I have to use the write-host, because it gives data to the user. What I am  really asking is there a way to determine in the function itself if the return value is pipelined or not? 

I need to increment the $PrevRes value for calculations, but when it is not pipelined anymore I do not want to output it to the screen. So at the very and I need only alfa beta and omega without the number at the end.

Comment: @SokIsKedu I'm not sure what you mean by "if the return value is pipelined" - in PowerShell, a function emits 0 or more objects, the last being after the return statement. If the next thing in the pipeline is another function, the objects will be sent on through to the it, otherwise returned to the caller

Comment: If your customer "wouldn't know how to use it", then why would he ask you to deliver it?

Comment: Well what I'm asking is there way to suppress the return value? like if I pass it to another function I can do calculations with it but if not I don't want the return value to be put on screen.


Well the customer is partially familiar with powershell and pipeline, but he won't be satisfied if he need to add anything more than that.

Comment: Oh I made a mistake in the title and missed the word not.
It should have been like Powershell: Supress the output to console if it is not pipelined

Comment: Saved the day!  honestly.

Answer (score 1):

@Mathias is correct but from the looks of your question you are using the `Write-Host` outputs as your actual return values for the user rather than actually returning data.  In which case you really want to do something more like this.  but as was already said, DO NOT use Write-Host for anything outside of early development/debugging of a script.

```
Function test1
{
  param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
  $PrevRes = @())
  $PrevRes += 'alpha'
  return ($PrevRes)
}
```